# ReferenceError: "Item" is not defined

Tags: qt, reference, qml

I want to check if an item of component is vissible or not but I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code but error is "ReferenceError: tagFilterPlaylist is not defined" how to solve this?

```
Repeater {
    id: tagRepeater
    model: main.playListBrowseModel
    Component {
            id: componentTagFilterPlaylist

            BasicUI.Tag {
                id: tagFilterPlaylist
                tag: "playlist"
                selected: true

                
            }
        }

    Loader {
        id: filterLoader
        sourceComponent:
            if (item_type === "playlist"){
                console.debug("check"+tagFilterPlaylist)
                if (!tagFilterPlaylist) {
                    tagFilterPlaylist.visible = true;
                    return componentTagFilterPlaylist
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm suprised that username is still available... :-o You have put `tagFilterPlaylist` in a Repater, so in laymens words, there are multiple. What is the goal of your piece of code? I think you have to rethink the way of coding it

Comment: @Amfasis I like to display the Component only once even if there are more items with the item_type="playlist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to an id within a Component because you first need to have an instance of that Component. What you should do is simply keep a boolean property outside the `Repeater` that keeps track of whether or not you're displaying your one and only `tagFilterPlaylist`.

```
property bool playlistVisible: false
Component {
    id: componentTagFilterPlaylist
    ...
}

Repeater {
    id: tagRepeater
    model: main.playListBrowseModel

    Loader {
        id: filterLoader
        sourceComponent:
            if (item_type === "playlist"){
                if (!playlistVisible) {
                    playlistVisible = true;
                    return componentTagFilterPlaylist
                }
            }
    }
}
```